# Is there any way to include the name of the interface when implementing the method

Tags: java, java-annotations

Is there any way to include the name of the interface when implementing the method? If I have to implement 3 interfaces, then it would be hard to remind me where the implemented method comes from.

If I have 2 interface required to implement the same method name. How can I tell which method I am implementing?

```
public interface BarInt {
void method();
}
public interface GeeInt{
void method();
}
public class Foo implements BarInt, GeeInt{

@Override
public void method() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can always leave a comment.

Comment: I know, but is there any java technical way?

Comment: Method Names should always *express what the method does*. In which interface a method is declared is a *technical detail* and no useful information for the reader of your code.

Comment: if comments aren't "technical" enough you could use javadoc annotations with the description containing the information you are after

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: On the contrary, an `@Override(BarInt.class)` or similar annotation would be useful for the same reasons `@Override` is: it helps ensure you're overriding what you think you are, and it helps make it clear why some methods exist, if they're only there to satisfy an interface contract. For example, `add` on an immutable `List`.

Comment: Can I suggest that not being able to remember which interface's method you're implementing might suggest that you're implementing too many interfaces in a single class? Remember: classes should have a [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle); if it's a Foo *and* a Bar *and* a Baz, then it's not really doing that.

Comment: Normally the IDE's show you from where the method comes and shows you a little sign, that this method comes from an interface... But of course you will only see it in the IDE and not in the code by itself.

Comment: If you're implementing `BarInt` and `GeeInt`, which interface is `method()` "from"? Which name do you want to have inserted automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just use a `@see` javadoc comment

```
public interface BarInt {
    void method();
}

public class Foo implements BarInt{

    /**
     * @see BarInt#method()
     */    
    @Override 
    public void method() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn’t a bad idea, but it’s worth noting that the generated javadoc will already have a link to the interface method which that method is implementing.  Notice the **Specified by:** section in the [documentation of String.length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--).

Comment: @VGR sure, but this would have it in the code which was the question. I wouldn't even think to look in the javadoc if I had the source in front of me. Of course I'd just use the IDE to jump to definition, but it's what the OP requested

Answer (score 0):

Novaterata's answer in good, this is a similar approach with annotations.

---

You can always roll your own annotations.

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Source {

    Class value();

}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
@Source(List.class)
@Override
public boolean add(Object o) {
    return false;
}
```

With the [retention policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) of `Source` the annotation will not be part of the bytecode. It only serves as additional information for the reader, IDE and compiler.

Answer (score -2):

Design wise name of method would reflect what the method does and you should be able to co-relate with the Interface the method belongs to.

De-bugging wise, most editor will take you the implemented Interface and method on few key strokes/clicks.