# Add the name of the interface to an automatically overridden method in Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

There's a previous related question about this here:

[Is there any way to include the name of the interface when implementing the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090032/is-there-any-way-to-include-the-name-of-the-interface-when-implementing-the-meth)

But I'm asking if there's a way so IntelliJ Idea does it itself when it generates these method automatically. It'd be great if the @Override annotation had some syntax like @Override(from_class), so you can have things like:

@Override("Comparable")
Integer compareTo(Object o) {
...
}

But that's not the case.

I've played a bit with the templates but thereis no ${OVERRIDDEN_FROM} or similar variable available with the name of the interface/class the method is overridden from, so that seems like a dead end too.

So, does anyone know a way to do this? Aside for requesting it to IntelliJ...

Comment: I don't know about a way to generate syntax like what you mentioned but if you're just looking for a way to see the override's origin and can do without in-code references, you can try using a hotkey. Pressing Ctrl+Q in Windows (^+J in macOS) should bring up the method's documentation which says the original method and class.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I'm aware of that, but I would like to have it in the code itself so I can see it in a glance, without having to request that information with additional mouse clicks or key strokes. Cheers!